# html5 comments make impact on the result but why?

Tags: html

what is the difference between

```
<ul> 
<li>Home</li><!-- 
---> <li> About</li> <!--- 
--> <li> Project</li> 
</ul>
```

and

```
<ul> 
<li> Home</li> 
<li> About</li> 
<li> Project</li> 
</ul>
```

the browser add some margin for second items

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific i mean share the code or screenshot from browser inspection ?But i prefer reset browser stylesheet first with css like following:

```
*{margin:0;}
```

Comment: This is the link where you find it. just change the legal code like second items http://codepen.io/rlacorne/pen/qwaIc

Comment: you have a div as a child of a ul, I would guess this is where the problem comes from. btw, it looks ok in chrome.